# Which Sparse Matrix Solver Libraries can I run on Android?

Tags: pde, linear-algebra, libraries, performance

The title says most of it.

I'm looking for a lightweight and easy-to-use library that I can use for Android (NDK) projects.
For dense stuff I like using Eigen but I haven't found many comprehensive (and documented!) libraries for sparse stuff that "just work" in a project.

PETSc seems a little heavy with all these MPI things but that's only my first impression.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What languages can android apps be written in?

Comment: Java or C++ or both combined (which is the recommended way).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try building [CSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/), which seems to have no dependencies other than the C standard library, judging from the source. (You can strip out the MATLAB interface, or just not build it.) Other routines on [Tim Davis' sparse linear algebra algorithms](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/) web site may also have few or no dependencies (for instance, you can build UMFPACK using its internal BLAS library instead of an external high-performance BLAS implementation).

Answer (score 3):

Yousef Saad's Sparskit has no dependencies just a bunch of simple Fortran routines.

Though Fortran on Android can be hard. For start see [here](http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-fortran-step-by-step-part-1.html).

Other option is to use the simple routines that come with the book "Templates for the Solution of Linear Systems: Building Blocks for Iterative Methods" available [here](http://www.netlib.org/templates/).